# can i use php code in AMP?

Tags: amp-html, google-amp

I have a site. I want to create Google AMP code for my site. What is the best way to transfer data between my existing site & new google AMP site. I make a decision to create a new domain for my existing site. Is it good or bad?

Answer (score 1):

> transfer data between my existing site & new google AMP site

well not sure what you mean there... You don't really transfer data, you are just creating a new webpage that follows AMP rules, which is then linked to your old site's page with a meta tag.

php is a server-side language. When somebody makes a request for index.php the php code inside index.php will execute in your server and you will only remain with html, css and js, which are at the end served to the user.

It  is definitely good to implement AMP in my opinion, especially if ranking on top of google search is one of your top priorities.

Comment: why did my answer get downvoted? what did I say wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**Can I use PHP code in AMP?**

Yes, you can use because PHP files can contain text, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and PHP code.

> **Note** : AMP pages are built with 3 core components AMP HTML, AMP JS and AMP Cache, you can use embedded inline css between  `<style amp-custom> </style>` tag on head.

**What is the best way to transfer data between my existing site & new google AMP site?**

Make the separate page for AMP and make your page discover able with `canonical` and `amphtml` tag

[**For more information visit the site**](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/converting/discoverable)

I don't think you need new domain for amp purpose.

Comment: Thanks For your valuable answer.

Answer (score 0):

AMP is a client (browser) side framework. PHP is a server side program. So, the two are unrelated.